# enable http-bind on openfire

Tags: xmpp, openfire, strophe

I am trying to enable BOSH connection over Openfire so that i can create a XMPP client over a web. curretly i am testing it with the strophe.js.

the problem is  when i try to fire following url in a browser i am getting

```
http://www.mydomain.com:7070/http-bind
```

following error

```
HTTP ERROR 400


    Problem accessing /http-bind/. Reason:

        Bad Request
    Powered by Jetty://
```

here is my server setting , i saw few threads but they arent helpful

[image]

**update**

i have made a connection using strophe but i am getting following error in browser trance

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your update Strophe is sending OPTIONS HTTP requests which means that it is negotiating cross domain communication. Requests are painted red which means that this is failing for some reason. Probably misconfiguration.
There is a nice article about that here: http://metajack.im/2010/01/19/crossdomain-ajax-for-xmpp-http-binding-made-easy/

Otherwise, when Strophe does its regular BOSH communication it uses POST method.

Answer (score 10):

its now working in my system.

i think your error encountered may actually be a configuration issue with the openfire.

It is designed to reply with HTTP 400 Bad Request if there is no  element in the request. You can test this yourself by providing a  element in your query.

Try the following URL in your browser:

```
 http://www.servername:7070/http-bind/?<body rid="1"/>
```

Comment: This worked for me in testing to see if the server was working. You will get error 400 without a body elements. With the element you get a BOSH object back. It also works by browsing to that link.

Comment: This Helps me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is correct. The page the browser displays to you is also normal. Openfires BOSH component is not designed to work in a Browser with HTTP GET, only with BOSH clients like strophe. Try to connect with strophe.

Comment: which browser? make sure your browser allows cross domain requests.

Answer (score 0):

You should use proxy to repost the request to the openfire server . Because, the js post cannot support cross domain.

Notes: 
1.I use jsjac , but I think it's not important .
2.If you sure your config is right , please restart you openfire server . It's my experience .

Answer (score 0):

If server is properly configured it should display

```
HTTP ERROR: 404

Problem accessing /http-bind/. Reason:

  Not Found
Powered by Jetty://
```

The Bad Request was gone when I uninstall and reinstall Openfire as in
[here](http://ubuntu-for-humans.blogspot.com/2009/11/uninstall-openfire-from-ubuntu-system.html).

Answer (score 0):

Below works for me, i am pinging the openfire server after some interval so, clients remains alive...
i just append "/?<body rid='1'" with the server name and i don't have 400 bad request error.

```
 XMPPconnection.sendIQ($iq({ to: XMPPserver+"/?<body rid='1'/>", from: CurrentUserJID, type: "get" }).c('ping', { xmlns: "urn:xmpp:ping" }));
```